# Snakemake: rule for using many inputs for one output with multiple sub-groups

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake, vcf-variant-call-format

I have a working pipeline I'm using for downloading, aligning and performing variant calling on public sequencing data. The problem is that it can currently only work on a per-sample basis (*i.e* sample as each individual sequencing experiment). It doesn't work if I want to perform variant calling on a group of experiments (such as biological and/or technical replicates of a sample). I've tried to solving it, but I couldn't get it work.

Here's a simplification of the alignment rule:

```
rule alignment:
    input:
        rules.download.output.fastq
    output:
        '{group}/alignment/{sample}.bam'
    shell:
        "bash scripts/02_alignment.sh {wildcards.group} {wildcards.samples}"
```

And the same for the variant calling:

```
rule variant_calling:
    input:
        rules.alignment.output
    output:
        '{group}/variants/{sample}.vcf.gz'
    shell:
        "bash scripts/03_variant_calling.sh {wildcards.sample} {wildcards.group}"
```

This works just fine, as there is a single `.vcf` file generated for each aligned `.bam` file. But what I would like to do is to generate a single `.vcf` file from an arbitrary number of `.bam` files. I have a `pandas` dataframe containing all the `sample` names and their corresponding `group`. I would essentially like to change the `output` of the second rule to be `'{group}/variants/{group}.vcf'`, but everything I've done has failed in some way.

The idea I had was to provide the rule with all the per-group aligned `.bam` files as input and then just give the script it runs the directory where they all lie. The problem is that I can't find a way to give an input in this per-group manner: either I give per-sample (as the working pipeline) or I give ALL the `.bam` files for EACH group variant calling, regardless of what group they actually belong to. I can't use just wildcards, as the `{sample}` wildcard is not present in the last output. I also tried using functions as input, but that lead to the same problems as above.

The crux of the matter seem to be the layers of grouping: if I wanted to perform variant calling on all aligned `.bam` files in the dataset as a whole, that would probably work fine, give my above mentioned problems. The problem comes with sub-groups for the dataset as a whole:

```
  sample1      sample2             sample1      sample2      sample3
     |            |                   |            |            |
     |            |                   |            |            |
     --------------                   ---------------------------
            |                                      |
            |                                      |
          group1                                 group2
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use some kind of structure to keep your samples in groups:

```
GROUPS = {
    "group1":["sample1","sample2"],
    "group2":["sample1","sample2","sample3"]
}
```

then something like this:

```
rule all:
    input:
         expand("{group}/variants/{group}.vcf.gz", group=list(GROUPS.keys()))

rule alignment:
    input:
        rules.download.output.fastq
    output:
        '{group}/alignment/{sample}.bam'
    shell:
        "bash scripts/02_alignment.sh {wildcards.group} {wildcards.samples}"

rule variant_calling:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: expand("{group}/alignment/{sample}.bam", group=wildcards.group, sample=GROUPS[wildcards.group]
    output:
        '{group}/variants/{group}.vcf.gz'
    shell:
        "bash scripts/03_variant_calling.sh {input} {output}"
```

of course there are missing rules that you didn't show but I think you'll get the point !

The shell command from rule variant_calling might be hard to handle but you can alway define a directory as params like:

```
params: groupAlignDir = "{group}/alignment"
```

and use that in the shell:

```
"bash scripts/03_variant_calling.sh {params.groupAlignDir} {output}"
```

and get all the bam file in the directory in your script "variant_calling.sh"

Comment: Oh, great! I was always thinking in terms of "sample to group", rather than listing all the samples IN a group as an input. Getting the input directory I solved by using `$(dirname {input[0]})` as an argument to the script, as this was similar to other things I was using. Thanks a lot for the help!